# element.replaceWith in a custom directive's link only work at first time called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to Angularjs, and don't understand too much behind the scene. 
Basically I want to create an 'E' kink directive, base on the data in controller I dynamically create the html, like a whole 'table' thing, to replace the directive.

The directve in my html file is like this:

```
<matrixrows></matrixrows>
```

My directive code is like this:

```
angular.module('matrix', [.....])
.directive('matrixrows', [..., function (...) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            require: '^matrix',
            link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
                ......... 
                scope.$watch('currentPage', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    if (newValue && newValue != oldValue) {

                        var html = "";
                        .......................
                        here is the code to generate the html
                        .......................
                        element.replaceWith(html);
                    }
                });
             }
    }])
```

Through watching **currentPage**'s change I recreate the html and replace the directive tag.
When the first time I change 'currentPage', the **element.replaceWith(html)** works fine. Then I change 'currentPage angin, the watching function will be triggered, but the **element.replaceWith(html)** won't work.

Then I stepped into Angularjs source code, I found, after the first time element.replaceWith's execution, **element[0].parentNode** became **null**, this caused the **replaceWith** crash.

Anybody know how to make it work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you're attempting to replace the same element several times. But once it's been replaced, it's gone. To solve this store the currentHtml in a variable. Something like this:

```
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
            ......... 
            var currentElement = element;
            scope.$watch('currentPage', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue && newValue != oldValue) {
                    .......................
                    var html = "";
                    here is the code to generate the html
                    .......................
                    var replacementElement = angular.element(html);
                    currentElement.replaceWith(replacementElement);
                    currentElement = replacementElement;
                }
            });
         }
```

Comment: Thanks!  I tried this, it doesn't work. BTW, element is from link's parameter, is passed in by angularjs.

Comment: Ahh.. I noticed after re-reading the code. Rewrote the answer. Did you try that as well?

Comment: Ahh.. also.. if your html is just a string, this won't work. You might have to also do a `angular.element(html)` to get a jQuery/jqLite element object.

Comment: html is a string. I am trying your suggestion, still no luck yet.

Comment: Great! it works. Just edit your code, add one line above the 'replaceWith': html = angular.element(html). I am going to accept it. You saved my life. Thanks again!

Comment: Wow, turns out to be such a simple solution, I have been messing about for hours with all sorts of things.

Comment: Interesting solution. Instead of getting into these element swapping loigc, I would rather just use `element.html(newHtmlContent);` to do the refresh.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using $compile(...) on the generated html string.

ex:

```
    link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
        ......... 
        var currentElement = element;
        scope.$watch('currentPage', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue && newValue != oldValue) {
                .......................
                var html = "";
                here is the code to generate the html
                .......................
                var replacementElement = $compile(html)(scope);
                currentElement.replaceWith(replacementElement);
                currentElement = replacementElement;
            }
        });
     }
```